# Problemas ao renderizar componente react após array filter

Tags: react

Boa noite,
Tenho um método que filtra um array e seta a variável de estado "transactions" com o resultado deste filter = newArrayTransactions, conforme podem abaixo.

O componente filho que passa o valor para o filter é um input do tipo text que estou usando o método onChange nele.
A ideia é renderizar dinamicamente outro componente que mostra todas as transactions na tela, com base nesse filtro que é digitado.
Funciona bem quando digito, mas quando deleto alguma letra "parece" que o filter não é executado.

```
const handleChangeInput = (value) =>{
const newArrayTransactions = transactions.filter(transaction =>{
  return transaction.description.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase())!== -1
})
setTransactions(newArrayTransactions)
```

Aqui esta a chamado ao componente filho passando a função acima

```
<CreateAndSearch onHandleInput={handleChangeInput}/>
```

Aqui esta o componente filho chamado acima

```
export default function CreateAndSearch({onHandleInput}) {

const handleInput = (e) =>{
    onHandleInput(e.target.value)
}

return (
    <div className='main-createAndSearch'>
        <button className='waves-effect waves-light btn'>
            <i className="material-icons left">add</i>
            NOVO LANÇAMENTO
        </button>
        <div className="input-field">
            <input id="filtro" type="text" onChange={handleInput}/>
            <label hmtlfor="filtro">Filtro</label>
        </div>
    </div>
)
```

}

Answer (score 0):

O método filter irá sempre filtrar o array cujo método é aplicado. Isso jamais aumenta seu tamanho pro valor original, filter na melhor das hipóteses irá retornar uma cópia do `transactions` anterior. Ou seja, você precisa manter uma referência ao array original com todas as opções. A seguir, um [exemplo funcional](https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-moon-t15kj?file=/src/App.js) de filtragem. Usei o `items` como constante, mas nada te impede de passá-lo como props.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import faker from "faker";
import "./styles.css";

const items = Array.from(Array(100).keys()).map(() => ({
  description: faker.commerce.productName(),
  id: faker.random.uuid()
}));

const filterFunction = value => transaction =>
  transaction.description.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) !== -1;

function CreateAndSearch({ onHandleInput }) {
  const handleInput = e => {
    onHandleInput(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div className="main-createAndSearch">
      <button className="waves-effect waves-light btn">
        <i className="material-icons left">add</i>
        NOVO LANÇAMENTO
      </button>
      <div className="input-field">
        <input id="filtro" type="text" onChange={handleInput} />
        <label hmtlfor="filtro">Filtro</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  const [transactions, setTransactions] = useState(items);

  const handleChangeInput = value => {
    setTransactions(items.filter(filterFunction(value)));
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>

      <CreateAndSearch onHandleInput={handleChangeInput} />

      <ul>
        {transactions.map(item => (
          <li key={item.id}>{item.description}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```